# math.random keeps giving me 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I stumbled on this problem that instead of giving me random number out of min, max, it gives me 0 every time! At this specific moment min was 0 (passive) and max was 1.02

Heres variable in my main app.js file:

```
var randomTicket = helper.getRandomInt(0, g_Totalcost);
```

Here's function in helper:

```
var getRandomInt = function(min, max) { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};
```

Comment: Just tried your function with `0, 1.02` and it works fine. Guess issue is with `g_Totalcost`

Comment: 1.02 is min or max?

Comment: With (0, 1.02), max - min + 1 = 2.02. Math.random will be a number between (0,1). Given that, about 50% of the time Math.floor(...) will return 0.

Comment: What are you expecting it to give you?

Comment: You haven't stated what the problem is.  You've said that you get a result of zero every time, but how does that result differ from what you expected?  What are you trying to achieve with your getRandomInt function?  Are you trying to get a random integer between min and max?  Inclusive or exclusive of min and max?  What should happen if min and/or max are not themselves integers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast (or convert to float value) the parameter `g_Totalcost`:

```
 var randomTicket = helper.getRandomInt(0, parseFloat(g_Totalcost));
```

Or, cast the parameters of the function:

```
var getRandomInt = function(min, max) { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (parseFloat(max) - parseFloat(min) + 1)) + parseFloat(min);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some kind of validation to prevent non-integer inputs, or the function won't behave as you expect.

My guess is that you forgot the following lines at the beginning of your function:

```
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.floor(max);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

**Here's some supporting analysis.**

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1.02 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
```

Simplifies to

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (2.02));
```

Math.random() returns a number between 0(inclusive) and 1(exclusive)

So let's calculate a few different possible results based on the value of Math.random().

- For Math.random()==0, the result is 0
- For Math.random()==0.45, the result is 0
- **For Math.random()==0.4999, the result is 1**
- For Math.random()==0.5, the result is 1
- For Math.random()==0.9, the result is 1
- For Math.random()==0.99, the result is 1
- **For Math.random()==0.999, the result is 2**
- **For Math.random()==0.9999999999999999, the result is 2**